# Split equation inside \sum or \int

Tags: math-mode, align

I'm trying to break up a sum of many terms into multiple lines as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
        L &= \sum { A && \text{This equation sums ABC} \\
                    \times B \\
                    \times C  }
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

but I get `Missing } inserted`.
The motivation is for the `\text` to not get pushed too far to the right.

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) sum does not take an argument, so remove those two braces and it should break just fine. Btw the brace set (are for sum) forms a group hiding the &'s from align*

Answer (score 2):

As already pointed out by @daleif in a comment, you must remove the spurious pair of curly braces that enclose the material after `\sum`. In addition, you should almost certainly provide alignment points for the material on rows 2 and 3.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\hrule % just to illustrate width of textblock
\begin{align*}
L &=     \sum   \text{A-stuff}   \tag*{This equation sums ABC} \\
  &\quad \times \text{B-stuff} \\
  &\quad \times \text{C-stuff}  
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `aligned`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
L &= \sum \Bigl( \begin{aligned}[t]
                 & A \\
                 & \times B \\
                 & \times C \Bigr)
                 \end{aligned}
  && \text{This text is not so far}
\\
M &= ABC && \text{This text is not so far}
\end{align*}
Just for a check:
\begin{align*}
M &= ABC && \text{This text is not so far} \\
K &= XYZ && \text{This text is not so far}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. Note how the parentheses don't neatly nest inside `aligned`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Tossing in parentheses and
`\phantom` instead of `\quad` ...

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
        L &= \sum \big( A \\
                    & \phantom{= \sum \big(} \times B \\
                    & \phantom{= \sum \big(} \times C
                \big)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

and it works nicely.
[image]

Now, is there a way to do something like this:

```
        L &\setphantom{= \sum \big(} A \\
                    & \getphantom \times B \\
                    & \getphantom \times C
                \big)
```